# Selecting subdocument in mongoose with a $

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my document structure:

```
"event": {
    "attendants": {
        "seekers": [
            {
                "$oid": "5bcdabd27e51de001576d289"
            },
            {
                "$oid": "5bc9b39c1a48dd0d7d521924"
            },
        ],
        "employers": [
            {
                "id": {
                    "$oid": "5bcda6477e51de001576d287"
                },
                "boothVisits": []
            },
            {
                "id": {
                    "$oid": "5bd0787e0f64cd001563ddbf"
                },
                "boothVisits": [
                    {
                        "$oid": "5bcda6477e51de001576d287"
                    },
                    {
                        "$oid": "5bd0787e0f64cd001563ddbf"
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

I need to select events in which current user's id is in the employers table. But there is the boothVisits as well there which prevents a simple `in` check. This is what I tried to do

```
Event.find().where('attendants.employers.$.id').equals(req.user._id).catch(e => console.log(e)),
```

But it ain't working. What am I missing? I'm assuming I'm using the `$` in a wrong way.

Comment: So do you want the whole document to be returned or a specific employer that matched?

Comment: The whole event where the employer id is in the `attendants.employers` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the whole document to be returned then you do not need to use `$`.

Simply use as below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
Event.find({"attendants.employers.id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)}),
```

This will check `id` under employers array if found then the whole event will be returned.

Comment: Thanks! I was overthinking it lol. I edited the answer so it matches the question + added mongoose for people who wouldn't know where the ObjectId came from